# Difference between -지/죠 and -(으)ㄴ가(요)?

Tags: difference, verb-endings

The title summerises my dilemma... What is the difference between -지/죠 and -(으)ㄴ가(요)?

I know 지/죠 but I've read that 은가 is more like I'm reflecting on something and asking for people's opinion implicitly. So I was like mmm but what's the difference then?

Now in my mind 지/죠 are like I'm sure about what I'm saying and I'm almost sure that the person I'm talking to agrees with my view 
On the other hand, I haven't understood 은가 yet but the feeling I have is that I'm more unsure about the thing I'm saying and I need reassure or I want to know the other person's opinion (because I don't know it).

Can you please explain me the usage and to which extent the feeling you get is different in terms of uncertainty of what you are saying and the intention to ask for confirmation

Edit: For example, I read this "그 사람 고향이 서울 아닌가요? (you doubt if you are wrong)". Here it seems that the speaker is asking for confirmation so I asked myself if I could also use -지/죠 in this sentence. In all the sentences I can think of with -지/죠, they are used when the speaker already knows the answer.
And here started the dilemma I summarized in the last part.

Comment: Can you add example sentences?

Comment: @Klmo I don't have example senteces... My question is on the theoretical side because I haven't understood -(으)ㄴ 가(요). If I'd write examples senteces they will probably be wrong

Comment: Well, have you consulted a dictionary like [this](https://krdict.korean.go.kr)? There *are* examples for -지, -ㄴ가, -은가, and -는가.

Comment: I've seen examples but this didn't answer to my doubts, that's why I wrote here.

Comment: If you do not bring specific examples here, there will be no way for me to know why you feel or think so. Others will also have to guess what you mean.

Comment: I added the example that started my thought process, hope it clears up what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mentioning "그 사람 고향이 서울 아닌가요?", you have asked the difference between "-(으)ㄴ가(요)?" and "-지/죠?" for *factual* questions, but the point is that you should learn what 아닌가 means.

Let me explain this set of factual questions including your example:

> A. 그 사람 고향이 서울 **아니죠**?
>
> B. 그 사람 고향이 서울 **아닌가요**?
>
> C. 그 사람 고향이 서울**인가요**?

With -지/죠, **Question A** shows that what the speaker *believes* to be true are (1) that the hometown of the/that person **is not** Seoul and (2) that the listener knows the truth. It also shows that the speaker *wishes to confirm* the truth. The listener will confirm whether Seoul is the hometown of the/that person if she/he knows the correct answer. Question A translates to "Her/His hometown is not Seoul, is it?" or "Her/His hometown is not Seoul, right?"

**Question B**, on the other hand, shows that the speaker *firmly believes* that the hometown of the/that person **is** Seoul and *wishes to confirm* the truth. You should note that I have just said "... *firmly believes* ... **is** Seoul..." *not* "... *thinks* ... **is not** Seoul" in consideration of the meaning of **아니다** used in *some* interrogative sentences. This 아니다 is defined in 한국어기초사전 as the following:

> 물음이나 짐작의 뜻을 나타내면서 어떤 사실이나 내용을 강하게 긍정하는 뜻을 나타내는 말.
>
> Used to express a wonder or guess and **strongly affirm** a fact or statement at the same time.
>
> ※ 주로 '아닐까', '**아닌가**' 등과 같은 의문문으로 쓴다.

Thus, it is 아닌가 (*not* -ㄴ가 alone) that relates to the speaker's certainty. In some contexts (for example, when the listener knows the truth), Question B will mean nearly the same as "그 사람 고향이 서울이죠?"; I would say that *Question B expresses greater certainty* since it can even sound like "I don't want to admit that I'm mistaken concerning her/his hometown." Question B translates to "Isn't her/his hometown Seoul?"

The speaker will use **Question C** if she/he *wishes to know* whether Seoul is the hometown of the/that person. This is a normal interrogative sentence translating to "Is her/his hometown Seoul?"; for some reasons, it seems to the speaker that Seoul is the hometown of the/that person.